# Create state for object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, activeadmin, state

Firstly I'm sorry for my english. Ha ha

So, I'm learning to create sites with Ruby on Rails so I started with that framework. I stuck for a few hours because I do not find the right method for something that I try to do.

I try to create a crowdfunding site. I have successfully installed and configured ActiveAdmin and configured it to create projects. I would now like to add a condition into these projects. I would like 4 states: "Empty" when the project is created, but not all features are filled. "Upcoming" when it met all the requirements. And then when it is ready it should get "Upcoming" state. I want my project management panel to be represented on activeadmin. I have a select box that would change the project status to "Validate" or "No validate".

So I thought to simply use the tool 'if condition' to do the above, but my problem is I have no idea of ​​where I should put it. If I put it into the active admin controller, a controller would be created for projects or in my project model? Should I create a method and if so when to call it? Maybe do something else? I struggle to see clearly the whole picture.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: I think state machine gem is answer for your problems: https://github.com/geekq/workflow Combined with custom active_admin actions.

Comment: I used the Statesman final and managed to do what I wanted. Thanks for your advice !
(I don't know how I can marked is answered)